# Cohomology groups of the dihedral groups with coefficients in its cyclic subgroup of index $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

The group cohomology of the dihedral groups with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is given in (the references of) this question:

[Group cohomology of dihedral groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294806/group-cohomology-of-dihedral-groups/1294862#1294862)

***question:***
How to compute the cohomology groups of the dihedral groups with coefficients in its cyclic subgroup of index $2$ by applying the universal coefficiant theorem to the aforementioned results?

Comment: What is the action of the group on this subgroup? Is it conjugation in the group?

Comment: Yes, it's conjugation in the group. I forgot to mention this.